# How to judge whether two groups of sequences are equal in cycles?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

There's a set of arrays that I want to remove repeated elements that are equal after rotation:

```
arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 5,1}};
```

The elements `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, `{2, 3, 4, 5, 1}`and `{5, 1, 2, 3, 4}`are the same after operation `RotateLeft`. I want to delete the duplicate elements and only get `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `{4, 3, 2, 5, 1}`.

```
DeleteDuplicates[arr, RotateLeft[#1] == #2 &]
```

However, the above operation can only delete the elements that are equal after one shift.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another idea is to make use of the fact that [`Cycles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cycles) canonicalizes. For example:

```
Cycles[{{5,1,2,3,4}}]
```

> Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]

So,

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, Cycles @* List]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 5, 1}}

Answer (score 7):

If we consider the list elements as graph vertices with an edge between each consecutive pair (cyclically), then two lists are equivalent if they can be mapped to graphs with the same edges.  In code:

```
graphs[list_] := <| # -> Sort@Thread[# -> RotateLeft[#]] & /@ list |>
```

So then:

```
graphs[arr]

(*
  <| {1,2,3,4,5} -> {1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->1}
   , {2,3,4,5,1} -> {1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->1}
   , {5,1,2,3,4} -> {1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->1}
   , {4,3,2,5,1} -> {1->4, 2->5, 3->2 ,4->3, 5->1}
   |>
*)
```

And:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, graphs[arr]]

(* {{1,2,3,4,5}, {4,3,2,5,1}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, Mod[# - #[[1]], 5] &]
```

does what you want. It replaces rotation operations by basuc integer arithmetic.

However, this exploits that only the numbers 1--5 appear in the lists. I don't know whether that is your actual use case...

The following would be a more general method:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, -1][[1]] - 1] &]
```

It normalizes the entries of `arr` by determining the smallest entry and rotating it in front.

Comment: My problem is that four couples sit around a round table and list the ways in which each couple is not adjacent (1488).

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 5,1}};
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Sort[Table[RotateLeft[#, i], {i, 1, 5}]] &] // Length
```

> `2`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and the most solid  solution is

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, Sort[NestList[RotateLeft, #, Length[#] - 1]] &]
```

If this solution is too slow for you, you might devise something like

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, RotateLeft[#, Last[Ordering[#]]] &]
```

But the latter works only if you know that there are no repetitions in each group.
For example, it does not work for

```
arr={{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}};
```

The former solution always works, but is slower. For example, for

```
arr = Table[RandomSample[Range[7]], 10^4];
```

the average evaluation time differs by a factor of 3 (0.062 sec. vs 0.023 sec.).

Answer (score 2):

Define an orbit index using `CyclicGroup`:

```
orbitIndex = Association[Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &] @
      GroupOrbits[CyclicGroup[Length @ First @ #], #, Permute]] &;

DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr, orbitIndex[arr]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 5, 1}}
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicates[arr, orbitIndex[arr][#] == orbitIndex[arr][#2] &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 5, 1}}
> ```

An example with repeated elements:

```
arr2 = arr /. 3 -> 2
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 2, 4, 5}, {2, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {5, 1, 2, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 2, 5, 1}}
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr2, orbitIndex[arr2]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 2, 4, 5}, {4, 2, 2, 5, 1}}
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicates[arr2, orbitIndex[arr2][#] == orbitIndex[arr2][#2] &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 2, 4, 5}, {4, 2, 2, 5, 1}}
> ```

Symbolic elements:

```
arr3 = arr /. MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}]
```

> ```
>  {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, {"B", "C", "D", "E", "A"},
>   {"E", "A", "B", "C", "D"}, {"D", "C", "B", "E", "A"}}
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[arr3, orbitIndex[arr3]]
```

> ```
> {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, {"D", "C", "B", "E", "A"}}
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicates[arr3, orbitIndex[arr3][#] == orbitIndex[arr3][#2] &]
```

> ```
> {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, {"D", "C", "B", "E", "A"}}
> ```